# django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: (no solution yet)

Tags: django, django-models

The problem is I just made some changes and inserted a new column **total_price** field, but its not reflecting  (i mean to say after migrations its still showing the error below_

i have checked many solutions none of them seems to work

Stuck on this for 2 hours: thanks in advance

```
no such column: orders_cartitem.total_price  <-- error


return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: orders_cartitem.total_price




class CartItem(models.Model):
    menu_item = models.ForeignKey(MenuItem, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    total_price = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    def __str__(self):
        return "This entry contains {} {}(s).".format(self.quantity, self.menu_item)
```

**migration file** updated

```
migrations.CreateModel(
            name='CartItem',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('quantity', models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)),
                ('total_price', models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, default=0.0, max_digits=10)),
                ('cart', models.ForeignKey(null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='orders.cart')),
                ('menu_item', models.ForeignKey(null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='menus.menuitem')),
            ],
        ),
```

Comment: So you've created migrations with `makemigrations` and applied them with `migrate`? Can you make sure the new column is indeed in that latest migration file?

Comment: did you run both `makemigrations` and `migrate`?

Comment: Yes tried couple of times , also tried deleting migrations then running command again , no avail

Comment: you're right field is there in migration file @AKX but it is still giving me this error